Substitution lemma for many-sorted logic
I am looking for a reference that contains an analogous of the first-order substitution theorem for many sorts. The single sort version of this theorem reads as follows (cf. Schöning's Logic for Computer Scientists):

Let F and G be equivalent formulas. Let H be a formula with an occurrence of F as subformula. Then H is equivalent to H' where H' is a formula obtained from H by substituting an occurrence of subformula F by G.

